# Botkit Slack app - May I know how can I send a DM to user who installs slack app?

Tags: slack, botkit

I am using botkit to develop slack app. I would like to know how can I send Direct Message to user who installs Slack App to their team.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `controller.on('event_name', function (bot, message) { ... })` handler to hook on different events. Full list of Slack events is listed in [docs](https://api.slack.com/events). In my opinion you can use [team_join](https://api.slack.com/events/team_join) event. This event is triggered when a new user accepts an invitation to join the team and signs into it.

Example:

```
controller.on('team_join', function (bot, message) {
  bot.api.chat.postMessage({channel: response.channel.id, text: 'Welcome', as_user: true}, function (err, response) {
      // Process postMessage error and response
  })
})
```